# How to force two figure's and one figure* on the same page in a twocolumn document?

Tags: graphics, floats, positioning, two-column, figure-placement

Consider following MWE

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzducks}

\title{Debug}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \center
    \tikz\randuck;
    \caption{Duck}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \center
    \tikz\randuck;
    \caption{Duck}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure*}[h]
    \center
    \tikz\randuck;
    \caption{Big Duck}
\end{figure*}

\clearpage

\lipsum[2]

%\begin{figure*}[h]
%   \center
%   \tikz\randuck;
%   \caption{Big Duck}
%\end{figure*}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[h]
    \center
    \tikz\randuck;
    \caption{Duck}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

I meant to have one page with Figure 1 and Figure 2 next to each other (which `ht` should do), and Figure 3 underneath them on the same page (which is why I commented out the figure at its original location in the code and put it directly beneath Figure 2 in the code). You see in the picture that I failed, what can I do?

Note that I do not mean to use subfigures, but three distinct figure floats with their respective captions.

I also added a `\clearpage` hoping that this would flush the figures, but it also does not work.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force figure placement in text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text)

Comment: Specifically, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8631/107497, which begins "do not use a floating environment if you do not want it float."  Note that `[ht]` will not put two figures next to each other.  It may put them sequentially, as in this case, or it may put them at the top of consecutive pages.

Comment: you can not use `[h]` wiith `figure*` so `\begin{figure*}[h]` means not `t` not `p` so it can not be placed anywhere until flushed witth `\clearpage`

Comment: also never use `\center` as a command, always `\centering`

Comment: @Teepeemm -- The cited question doesn't deal with `figure*`.  That's a special case, and the usual floating mechanism only allows `figure*` at the *top* of a page, while this OP wants it below two half-width figures.  The [`hvfloat` package](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb42-3/tb132voss-hvfloat.pdf) provides more flexibility, but I don't think it includes that option.  That leaves [brute force](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb35-3/tb111beet-banner.pdf).  But maybe I'm just not aware of something automatic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]

figures that should float together should be in the same float, that's why `figure` allows multiple `\caption`

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzducks}

\title{Debug}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure*}[t]
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
    \tikz\randuck;
    \caption{Duck}    
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
    \tikz\randuck;
    \caption{Duck}    
  \end{minipage}

    \centering
    \tikz\randuck;
    \caption{Big Duck}
\end{figure*}


\lipsum[2]


\lipsum[1]



\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't know that one can put multiple `\caption`s in one `figure`!

Answer (score 7):

Like this?

[image]

Images, first two are inserted into `parboxes`, are merged in one `figure*` floats. Consequently they will appear on the top of the next page from point of `figure*` insertion:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzducks}

\title{Debug}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure*}[t]
    \centering
\parbox{0.45\linewidth}
{
    \tikz\randuck;
    \caption{Duck}
}
\parbox{0.45\linewidth}
{
    \tikz\randuck;
    \caption{Duck}
}

\bigskip
    \tikz\randuck;
    \caption{Big Duck}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \tikz\randuck;
    \caption{Duck}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: @JohnKormylo, you are right. Corected now.